# How to change attribute uniqueness in openldap and phpldapadmin

Tags: php, ubuntu, ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

How do I change the uniqueness of an attribute in openLDAP and phpldapadmin? I always get the following message:

> Warning: ldap_mod_add(): Modify: Type or value exists in /var/www/html/Cou.php on line 40

Comment: You modify the configuration of the 'unique' overlay, but are you sure you want to remove this constraint? Whoever set up the LDAP server deliberately put it in there for presumably very good reasons. You may break all sorts of things. What is the attribute?

Comment: the attribute was the name of a file which maybe uploaded twice for some reason.

Comment: What is the name of the attribute? And why was it made unique in the first place? The only things that should be unique are things like email addresses, UIDs, etc.

Comment: The attribute is cn.